# O(1) vs O(n) in Space Complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
O(1)
function sum(arr) {
   let total = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i]; 
    }
    return total;
}
```

```
function double(arr) {
   let newArr = [];
   for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       newArr.push(2 * arr[i]);
       }
   return newArr;
}
```

So i studying algorithm using javascript.
The first one I think is O(1) because it has constant space. The reason why it has constant space is because number data types are constant space in javascript.
The second one makes a new array which is generally O(n) which makes its space complexity O(n).
Am i understanding it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly right, though it's not *just* that the second code makes a new array - you have to look at what the array *contains*. Here, on every iteration, a new number is pushed to the array. So if you have N items in the `arr` argument, you'll have N numbers in the `newArr` as well.

One array * N numbers means O(n) space used.

If the `arr` was changed to contain something *else* more complex, such as additional sub-arrays, the space complexity could be larger.

Comment: And for completeness, if the loop doesn't insert a new item in the array every loop, the complexity could be below `O(n)`, as well.  If it inserts only powers of two, it'd be `O(log n)` for example. If it only inserts two items (e.g., extracting min and max) it'd be `O(1)`.